# How to move (i.e. reset) a local git upstream tracking branch? e.g. to "undo" a `git fetch origin main`

Tags: git, git-remote, git-reset

AFAIK the only git command to manipulate upstream tracking branches is `git fetch` (and [other commands that trigger a fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72145463/when-would-git-move-remote-tracking-branches-automatically-without-git-fetch)), but they only really allow a "fast forward" operation against the remote branch.

I would like to have more control and be able to "reset" it like any other local branch, without affecting remote. I *think* one way is to modify the file at `.git/refs/remotes/origin/<branchname>` to point to a different SHA, but is that correct/safe?

#### Why: to decouple multiple ongoing branches/workstreams

Let's say I've got:

```
* (HEAD -> kache/foo, origin/kache/foo) done, ready to push
| * (kache/bar) almost done, commits are atomic
|/
| * (kache/baz) still wip, commits are a mess
|/
* (main, origin/main)
```

I discover that `foo` needs a fresh `main` (for w/e reason), so I fetch `origin/main`, rebase `foo` on top, and then get it merged.

But now, `main` is far behind `origin/main`. Before I context switch, getting back a "clean slate" means forwarding `main` to `origin/main` and rebasing all branches on top. Should rebase conflicts arise, `bar` will be easy to fix, but `baz` won't.

I generally have many local dev branches and working on a single one (`foo`) has caused a workflow interruption on every other branch. In addition, the more "wip" like `baz` there are, the worse the mass-rebase overhead will be.

I've already tried/got various "[rebasing a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315285/rebasing-a-tree-a-commit-branch-and-all-its-children)" solutions. I'll keep trying, but solving the general-case means being resilient against (multiple) rebase conflicts, being abort-able (atomic), retryable (recorded resolutions), etc, and AFAIK a general-case turnkey solution doesn't exist.

In this situation, I'd like to just reset `origin/main` back to `main`. Once `foo` is merged, I can delete my local `foo`, reset my `origin/main`, and immediately context-switch to `bar` or `baz`. Unlike a mass-rebase, it would be fast and would always work. I'd be able to fetch `main` and mass-rebase later when it's convenient, decoupling my `foo` workstream from every other.

Comment: Can you detail more why do you need to reset an upstream branch?

Comment: This question should not be closed. It is 100% on-topic and does not lack any significant information. Maybe an uncommon request, but perfectly valid question.

Comment: Thanks, hlovdal.  @HantsanialaEléo, I've added a "Why" section.

Comment: After reading many time, I still don't understant. Maybe I'm lacking somehitng but maybe  the use of gitflow may help you to manage your branch. https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

Comment: I don't have any issues managing _my_ branches, I'm decently proficient with git. The issue is that remote tracking branches aren't really considered "my branches".